# Electron: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm building my first electron desktop app and I'm getting a *"cannot find module"* error when I use `require()` in one file to import the other. **Both files are in the same folder and there's no misspelling.**.

Here's the main file `index.js`

```
const app = require('electron')
const store = require('./datacontainer') //Here I import the other file

if(store.users.length==0) { // throws exception: store is not defined
    ...
}
```

and below is the imported file `datacontainer.js`

```
var exp = module.exports = {};

exp.users = [{user1},{user2},...];

...
```

However, when I run the app and look at the console, it throws the following exeption;

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './datacontainer'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\mm_apps\report-viewer\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\common\reset-search-paths.js:35)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:473)
    at Module.require (module.js:586)
    at require (internal/module.js:11)
    at index.js:10
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

## UPDATES:

In the `index.html` where the `index.js` is used, the error goes away if I reference the script like the following

```
<script>
   require('./scripts/index')
</script>
```

but throws above error when referenced this way

```
<script src="./scripts/index.js"></script>
```

what gives?

Comment: @Akshay Anurag answer is clear enough to solve your q right?

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo, Not really. I ended up abandoning Electron and going with a Windows Form app as my client only uses Windows. I was under a tight deadline and with electron, I found myself spending hours learning how to do things that are otherwise trivial in Windows forms and debugging annoying errors instead of delivering results to my customer. I hope to revisit electron in the future, but my customers could care less what tech I use as long as the final product solves their problems.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

`<script src="./scripts/index.js"></script>`

it looks for the file on the server.

Something like:

`https://www.example.com/your-web-folder/scripts/index.js`

Using `Node.js`'s require resolves it according to the folder structure of your project.